# Laravel 5.3 Best practices - load lists from other models to populate dropdowns

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.3, laravel-blade

i'm new to Laravel and i'm using InfyOm laravel generator to create an app. 
I came to an issue and would like to know what is the best practice to do this:

I have a model "Mission". When creating a mission, it need to have a client id and agent id associated with it.
In my view, i want to display 2 dropdown lists, one containing all the active clients (id + name) and the other containing all the active agents (id + name).

my controller

```
public function create()
{
    return view('missions.create');
}
```

my view blade

```
{!! Form::select('client_id', ?????? , null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
```

Thanks for your suggestions

Comment: Pass the list of clients and the list of agents to the view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most convenient way is to use `pluck()` method to build a list from a collection, for example:

```
public function create()
{
    return view('missions.create', [
        'users' => User::pluck('name', 'id')
    ]);
}
```

Then use `$list` variable:

```
{!! Form::select('client_id', $users , null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
```

Comment: It worked, thanks. Anyone having troubles with this, don't forget to include the namespace --> "use App\Models\User;" on top of your controller